# VScode API why can't I get the current line?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, text-editor, vscode-extensions

I am using typescript to write a vs code extension and for some reason I am unable to get the current line.

The function I am trying to make is:

```
function makeFrame()
{
    vscode.window.activeTextEditor.selection.active.line;
}
```

Which fails with error: Object is possibly undefined
The import statement is:

```
import {window, commands, Disposable, ExtensionContext, StatusBarAlignment, StatusBarItem, TextDocument} from 'vscode';
```

What am I doing wrong?

(I am both new to TypeScript and writing extensions for VS code)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`activeTextEditor` may be `undefined`. This indicates that there is no active editor and will happen for example when you first open a new workspace or when you close all editors

To fix, just add a quick check:

```
function makeFrame()
{
    const activeEditor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
    if (activeEditor) {
        activeEditor.selection.active.line;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Object is possibly undefined

Because there may or may not be an `activeEditor`.

You can do an explicit check:

```
function makeFrame() {
    const activeEditor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
    if (activeEditor != null) {
        activeEditor.selection.active.line;
    }
}
```

Or an [assertion](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/options/strictNullChecks.html) if you are sure:

```
function makeFrame()
{
    vscode.window.activeTextEditor!.selection.active.line;
}
```